# How to synchronize setter and getter?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency, enums

I'm new to Java and just need to find the correct syntax to synchronize this method.

I don't think I can change the template, I get "cannot edit in read-only editor." Normally I would just have the setter return the value.

This is just the general idea of the code, the syntax is not correct.

```java
public class Task extends AbstractTemplate<Service> {
    private Enum result;
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void execute(Map params) {
        result = this.executeService(params);
    }
    
    public Enum getResult() {
        return result
    }
}
```

The issue I'm running into of course is as I execute many concurrent requests to execute function and then immediately call getResult, the results returned do not correspond with correct params.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no good way to do that.

If `execute` and `getResult` are called from same thread you can put result in thread local variable. It is bad design, it is better to refactor you code so `execute` returns result directly.